# Desinging a dropdown list with different value attributes and display text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a translating system where I am using Google Translator API. So I need to have a dropdown list of languages where I have to pass the code of the languages to the API. I tried to do that using bootstrap, But it didnt work. I know how to do this part in HTML. But I preffer to do that in Bootstrap. This is what I have tried so far

```
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Region <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" >Spanish</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sinhala</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
            <li class="divider">Arabic</li>
            <li><a href="#">Quebec</a>
            </li><li><a href="#">Ontario</a>
            </li><li><a href="#">British </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Please give me an idea to proceed. Thank you in advance

Comment: check this link it almost have direct code you are looking for http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/language.html

Comment: <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Region <span class="caret"></span></a>
            
                <select class="input-medium bfh-languages" data-language="en"></select>
          
        </div>
        I used the above snippet. But it's still not working.I added the two .js files also

Answer (score 0):

Add a `data-*` attribute to your `a` tags. Attach a `click event` and get this `data-*` attribute and pass this to the `API`.

**Ex:**

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
   <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Region <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a data-code="spanishCode" href="#" >Spanish</a></li>
       <li><a data-code="sinhalaCode" href="#">Sinhala</a></li>
       <li><a data-code="portugueseCode" href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
       <li class="divider">Arabic</li>
       <li><a data-code="quebecCode" href="#">Quebec</a></li>
       <li><a data-code="ontarioCode" href="#">Ontario</a></li>
       <li><a data-code="britishCode" href="#">British </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Click Event**

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu li a').on('click',function(){
     var code=$(this).data('code');
     //pass this code in your API request and get the response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Definition and Usage**

1. The `data-*` attributes is used to store custom data private to the
   page or application.
2. The `data-*` attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data
   attributes on all HTML elements.
3. The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript
   to create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or
   server-side database queries).

The **data-*** attributes consist of two parts:

The attribute name should not contain any **uppercase letters**, and must be at least one character long after the prefix **"data-"**
The attribute value can be any string

**Note:** Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent

```
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select a Region <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" data-langcode = "sp" class="langclass">Spanish</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-langcode = "en" class = "langclass">english</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".langclass").on("click",function(){
    var code = $(this).data("langcode");//call this code in your functin
     callabelfunction(code);
})
```